# Importing photos saved in ios device's Documents folder to desktop

Tags: iphone

I'm creating a catalog/collection ios4 application. One element of the app lets the user take a picture which they use for a new item entry. The image they choose is then saved to their app's local Document folder.

I was wondering if it's possible to give the user the ability to import the photos to their desktop when they plug in their ios device. Like how iPhoto lets you import photos from your camera roll when you plug in your device

I've looked around, and all i can seem to find are posts on saving to the documents folder, and then retrieving the data within the app.

Any help would be great.

Thanks Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an intermediate web service to transfer the files.  Upload them to your service from the device, download them to the desktop.

Apple locks this stuff down pretty tight, so that might be your best bet.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but thanks for the advice i'll take a look into this. It sounds like good plan.